# Need help on css display state using localStorage and jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am building a multi-page form and it has a lot of conditional statements. Some of which deal with the display of particular DIVs based upon the selection of some other DIVs. To make my question simple I have created another form that works similarly, but is very short.

The first input field asks the "First Name." After it is filled with characters, two fields for "Middle Name," and "Last Name" appear. Originally, these two fields have "inline-style" of "display:none;" and hence are not displayed until the jQuery function displays them. Once the user fills out the form and hits submit, PHP validations run on the server.

For our purpose, let's fill the first input field then followed by two new fields displayed by jQUery, leave other fields blank and hit "submit." Of course, the PHP validations fail and we are shown the refreshed version of the form with all the form data gone and most importantly for my usage, the CSS display state for the two input fields gone. Now, I know I could add php to keep the values on the input fields, but that still does not solve my problem of keeping the CSS display state of the "display:none;" DIVs.

I need help with restoring the form data on the first field followed by the display of the other two fields with their data. I sort of know how the localStorage works, but I could not make it work here.

I very much appreciate anyone giving this their time.
Once again, thank you very much.

Here goes the code:

```
   <?php     
   $firstName = $middleName = $lastName = $email = $phone = $comment = $from = $name =     $subject = $subject2 = $message2 = $headers = $headers2 = $result = $result2 = '';
   $errors = array('firstName'=>'','middleName'=>'','lastName'=>'','email'=>'','phone'=>'','comment'=>'  ');
```

---

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))  {  /**checks if the submit button is pressed or not. only   executes below steps if the form is submitted.**/



//check first name input
if(empty($_POST['firstName'])){
    $errors ['firstName'] = 'Please enter your First Name <br />';
    } else {
        $firstName = $_POST['firstName'];
        if(!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/', $firstName)){
           $errors ['firstName'] = 'Only letters are accepted <br />';
        }
}


//check middle name input
if(empty($_POST['middleName'])){
    $errors ['middleName'] = 'Please enter your Middle Name <br />';
    } else {
        $middleName = $_POST['middleName'];
        if(!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/', $middleName)){
           $errors ['middleName'] = 'Only letters are accepted <br />';
            }
}

//check last name input
if(empty($_POST['lastName'])){
    $errors ['lastName'] =  'Please enter your Last Name<br />';
    } else {
        $lastName = $_POST['lastName'];
        if(!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/', $lastName)){
           $errors ['lastName'] = 'Only letters are accepted <br />';
        }
}

//check email input
if(empty($_POST['email'])){
    $errors ['email'] =  'Please enter your E-mail Address <br />';
    } else {
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
            $errors ['email'] = 'Email must be a valid email address <br />';
    }
        }

//check phone number input
if(empty($_POST['phone'])){
    $errors ['phone'] ='Please enter your Phone Number<br />';
    } else {
        $phone = $_POST['phone'];
        if(!preg_match('/^[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}+$/', $phone)){
            $errors ['phone'] = 'Only numbers separated by dashes are allowed <br />';
            }
        
    }

//check comment input
if(empty($_POST['comment'])){
    $errors ['comment'] = 'Please provide your feedback <br />';
    } else {
        $comment = $_POST['comment'];
            if(!preg_match('/^[\w,.!?\s]+$/',$comment)){
        $errors ['comment'] = 'Only letters, commas, and periods are allowed <br />';
    }
   }
if(array_filter($errors)){
    //let the user fill out form again
    echo '<script type = "text/javascript">alert("Submission failed due to error in    the input field. Please fill all the input fields and submit the form again. Thank you!")     </script>';
    } else {
        header('location:thank-you');
    }
 //php to send message to both client and the owner
$mailto = "a@b.com"; //web owners email addresss
$from = $_POST['email']; //senders email address
$name = $_POST['firstName']; //user's name
$subject = "You received a message";
$subject2 = "Your message has been submitted successfully"; //message title for client   email
$comment = "Client Name: ". $firstName. "wrote the following message". "\n\n". $_POST   ['comment'];
  $message = "Contact Form". "\n\n".
            "From -     ".  $firstName. "   ". $middleName. "   ". $lastName. "\n\n".
            "Email Id -     ".  $from. "\n\n". "Phone Number -     ". $phone. "\n\n".
            "FeedBack :". "\n\n". $_POST ['comment'];

$message2 = "Dear ". $firstName. ",". "\n\n". "Thank you for contacting us!";
$headers = "From: ". $from; //user entered email address
$headers2 = "From: ". $mailto; // this will receive to client
$result = mail($mailto, $subject, $message, $headers); //send email to the website    owner
$result2 = mail($from, $subject2, $message2, $headers2); //send email to the user or form submitter



}   // end of POST check

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1    /jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.1  /jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet"href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Muli">

    

        <title>Contact Form</title>

        <style>
            label{display:block;}

            .container{display:flex; flex-direction: row; flex-wrap: wrap;
            margin-top:10rem; justify-content: left; margin-left:3rem;}

            .flexItems{
                margin-right:1rem; margin-bottom:2rem;
            }

            #submit{
                margin-left:3rem;
                width:20em;
            }
            
            .comment{
                margin-left:3rem;
                }
            .red-text{
                color:red;
                }
            


        </style>

<script>

        $(document).ready(function() {
            
            

                $("#fName").change(function(){
                  if($(this).val() != ""  ){
                      $("#mName1").css("display","block");
                      $("#lName1").css("display","block");
                  } else {
                      $("#mName1").css("display","none");
                      $("#lName1").css("display","none");
                  }

              })

      })









</script>   



    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="" method="POST" auto_complete = "off" id = "form">
            <div class = "container">

                <div class= "flexItems">
                    <label>First Name</label>
                    <input id = "fName" type = "text" name = "firstName" >
                    <div class = "red-text"><?php echo $errors['firstName']; ?></div>
                </div>

                


                <div class= "flexItems" id = "mName1" style = "display:none;">
                    <label>Middle Name</label>
                    <input id = "mName" type = "text" name = "middleName" >
                    <div class = "red-text"><?php echo $errors ['middleName'];                              ?></div>

                </div>

                <div class= "flexItems" id = "lName1"style = "display:none;" >
                    <label>Last Name</label>
                    <input id = "lName" type = "text" name = "lastName" >
                    <div class = "red-text"><?php echo $errors ['lastName']; ?></div>

                </div>

                <div class= "flexItems">
                    <label>Email Address</label>
                    <input id = "eAddress" type = "email" name = "email" >
                    <div class = "red-text"><?php echo $errors ['email']; ?></div>

                </div>

                <div class= "flexItems">
                    <label>Phone Number</label>
                    <input id = "pNumber" type = "tel" name = "phone" >
                    <div class = "red-text"><?php echo $errors ['phone']; ?></div>

                </div>
                

                <div class= "comment">
                    <label>Comment</label>
                    <textarea rows = "6" cols ="60" name = "comment" placeholder =    "Please leave a comment. Thank you!" ></textarea>
                    <div class = "red-text"><?php echo $errors ['comment']; ?></div>

                </div>




                <div  id = "submit">
                    <button type= "submit" id = "submit" value = "Send my message    ASAP" name = "submit">Submit</button>
                </div>

            </div>

            

            
        </form>



    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you please only post the code that is relevant to your problem so it's easier to help you? ([mcve])

Comment: Just a hint about your validations: https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Comment: Hi, I just need a code snippet for localStorage using jQuery that when the form fails the validation and the page reloads, the "display:none;" divs are shown with the values that the User had put in.

Answer (score 0):

> I know I could add php to keep the values on the input fields, but that still does not solve my problem of keeping the CSS display state of the "display:none;" DIVs.

I would recommend using PHP to fill in the form values after submission and solve showing/hiding elements with JavaScript.

For example PHP would look like this: (using `htmlspecialchars` to escape quotes and other special characters and reading data directly from POST request)

```
<input
 id="fName"
 type="text"
 name="firstName"
 value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['firstName']); ?>"
>
```

*There is also possibility to keep values in localStorage if you prefer. I was able to find this jQuery plugin which does that - [Persist.js](https://www.jqueryscript.net/form/Persist-Form-Data-Local-Storage.html).*

Second task is to show/hide corresponding fields.

First of all, try to think about user experience when new fields appear or disappear. Maybe it's better to keep all the fields on the screen, disable/enable them etc. I can think of one case when fields can be hidden and it is when several options are presented for selection and the last option is 'other (please specify)' which allows to input custom response. I'll be adding this use case to the prototype bellow.

I'd recommend to create a single `updateVisibility` function that will show/hide needed blocks. It should be called when page loads (with data filled in with PHP) and when any form field is modified:

```
function updateVisibility() {
    // fname - show/hide mName/lName
    if ($("#fName").val() !== "") { // always use === or !== in JS for comparison
        $("#mName1").css("display", "block");
        $("#lName1").css("display", "block");
    } else {
        // hide inputs and clear values
        $("#mName1").val('').css("display", "none");
        $("#lName1").val('').css("display", "none");
    }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    // call when page is loaded
    updateVisibility()

    // and every time any field changes in the form
    $("#form").change(updateVisibility)
});
```

P.S. I've noticed and fixed several errors in HTML:

- tag attributes should not contain spaces - `id="fName"` (not `id = "fName"`)
- `label` tag requires `for` attribute - `<label for="fName">` (where `fName` is an ID of some other element to which label will point)

Please find prototype code bellow (only HTML part, StackOverflow does not run PHP). `Programming language` field is an example of how I think user experience should be, I've kept `Middle name`/`Last name` fields functionality like in your question.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Muli">



    <title>Contact Form</title>

    <style>
        label {
            display: block;
        }

        label.radio-label {
            display: inline;
        }

        .container {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            margin-top: 10rem;
            justify-content: left;
            margin-left: 3rem;
        }

        .flexItems {
            margin-right: 1rem;
            margin-bottom: 2rem;
        }

        #submit {
            margin-left: 3rem;
            width: 20em;
        }

        .comment {
            margin-left: 3rem;
        }

        .red-text {
            color: red;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        function updateVisibility() {
            // fname - show/hide mName/lName
            if ($("#fName").val() !== "") {
                $("#mName1").css("display", "block");
                $("#lName1").css("display", "block");
            } else {
                $("#mName1").val('').css("display", "none");
                $("#lName1").val('').css("display", "none");
            }
            // language other - show/hide language-other-block
            if ($('input[name="language"][type="radio"]:checked').val() === 'other') {
                $('#language-other-block').css('display', 'block');
            } else {
                $('#language-other-block').css('display', 'none');
                $('#language-other-input').val('');
            }
        }

        $(document).ready(function () {
            // call when page is loaded
            updateVisibility()
            // and every time any field changes in the form
            $("#form").change(updateVisibility)
        })
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <form action="" method="POST" auto_complete="off" id="form">
        <div class="container">

            <div class="flexItems">
                <label for="fName">First Name</label>
                <input id="fName" type="text" name="firstName">
                <div class="red-text">
                    <?php echo $errors['firstName']; ?>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="flexItems" id="mName1" style="display:none;">
                <label for="mName">Middle Name</label>
                <input id="mName" type="text" name="middleName">
                <div class="red-text">
                    <?php echo $errors ['middleName']; ?>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="flexItems" id="lName1" style="display:none;">
                <label for="lName">Last Name</label>
                <input id="lName" type="text" name="lastName">
                <div class="red-text">
                    <?php echo $errors ['lastName']; ?>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="flexItems">
                <label for="eAddress">Email Address</label>
                <input id="eAddress" type="email" name="email">
                <div class="red-text">
                    <?php echo $errors ['email']; ?>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="flexItems">
                <label for="pNumber">Phone Number</label>
                <input id="pNumber" type="tel" name="phone">
                <div class="red-text">
                    <?php echo $errors ['phone']; ?>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="flexItems">
                <div>Programming language</div>
                <div><input type="radio" name="language" value="js" id="language-js"><label class="radio-label"
                        for="language-js">JavaScript</label></div>
                <div><input type="radio" name="language" value="php" id="language-php"><label class="radio-label"
                        for="language-php">PHP</label></div>
                <div><input type="radio" name="language" value="other" id="language-other"><label class="radio-label"
                        for="language-other">other</label></div>
                <div id="language-other-block" style="display: none;">
                    <label class="radio-label" for="">Please specify: </label>
                    <input type="text" name="language-other" id="language-other-input">
                </div>
                <div class="red-text">
                    <?php echo $errors ['language']; ?>
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="comment">
                <label for="comment">Comment</label>
                <textarea rows="6" cols="60" id="comment" name="comment"
                    placeholder="Please leave a comment. Thank you!"></textarea>
                <div class="red-text">
                    <?php echo $errors ['comment']; ?>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="submit">
                <button type="submit" id="submit" value="Send my message ASAP" name="submit">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much Vitalii for pointing out my HTML errors. In my original project, I do use "PHP echo htmlspecialchars" to keep values on the fields. My problem was when the page reloaded, the values would be there but would not show up for the hidden fields until you would uncheck and check the option again. I liked the "plugin" solution that you mentioned. I might give it a try. But for now, I have managed to fix that problem by using "trigger" so that all jQuery run again after the form relaods.  Thanks again for your suggestions and solution!